# Can't Install or remove Bluetooth Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth

Upon using this

```
sudo apt-get purge blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

or

```
sudo apt -y install bluetooth
```

I get this error [Terminal screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r65v6.png)

Comment: For future post, please try and provide more logs in text form. 

Could you try and break up al your apt commands, and see what happens with each one? Try and remove one package at the time. If any errors, please update your current post to include the new errors.